# Codes not changing in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with android studio v4. I wrote some codes in Activity and run it with success. Now, When I change that code, There is no change in the program. For example, I added 5 records to SQLite-database as default and now, I want to add just one record. So I remove 4 records and run the project, But 5 records still showing.

I try to remove the application from device, Clean project, Rebuild project, Invalidate cache, and restart. But not be changed.

Can you help me?

Comment: have you checked your db entries ?

Comment: @Basi Yes, I only add data from one location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstall the android studio and the problem was solved.